# How to map date.doc in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I read technically firebase do not contain array and object but maps(similar to object) and to change date into array I have to use doc.data() function. My problem is that I have this structure and I want that one.

```
[{
uid: xxxxxx,
name: zzzzzz,
mon: {
[0]: {"name": "", "desc": ""},
[1]: {"name": "", "desc": ""}
}}]
```

My idea is setState that it contain only mon like

```
[{"name": "", "desc": ""}, {"name": "", "desc": ""}]
```

or maybe someone know how to get this structure when I post the date:

```
  displayName: user.displayName,
                  uid:  user?.uid,
                  modulyPV}
```

My try:

```
setUser(data.docs.filter((m) => m.mon).map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out solution. It is:

```
    const     datas = data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
                    setState(datas[0].mon)
```

topić to close.